# How to sniff udp between two windows applications on the same machine

Tags: windows, udp, packet-sniffer

How do I monitor the duplex udp traffic between two apps on my windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems RawCap is capable of sniffing packets on localhost. Have a look at it: http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap. The .pcap file it generates can be opened with Wireshark, so that you can easily see what's been transmitted. Let me know if it worked.